# How to replace word in text with Hashtag in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on [React Card](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-forest-jp8o9) which a social media card.

The body contains a `Text` component where it's responsible for displaying the text:

My component [Text](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-forest-jp8o9?file=/src/components/Card/Body/Text.jsx) looks like :

```
const Text = ({ content }) => (
    <div className="mt-2 mb-4 mx-4">
        <p className="text-sm text-justify">{content}</p>
    </div>
)
```

My issue is I'm displaying the `content` through `<p>` while the content can contain hashtag words which supposed to be a link.

This is the [Mockup](https://github.com/MenaiAla/react-social-media-card/blob/master/mockup/Social-Card.png).

This is what I made until now : [Implementation](https://jp8o9.csb.app/)

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: do you mean that `content` contains text with `#`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, exaclty, just check the code on sandbox.

Comment: but how do you get the links?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, the `Text` component recieve a JSON string, this string may contains `#` , but I'm wrapping the content only `p` where the hashtag should be a `link`, you get me ?

Comment: No, I don't, that's not very clear. What do you mean "JSON string"? What output are you expecting? And what have you done so far? Give a [mre] *in the question*, not offsite.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, it's just an example. I expected to set the `href` with the `word`.

Comment: do you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63617847/react-parse-string-with-variables/63618595#63618595)?

Comment: Again, I said in the question, **not** offsite.

Comment: please check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-brattain-p6ikz)

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim, it works well and I made some changes on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Bousadjra solution is by `splitting` the `content` and `mapping` each word by returning an `href` where the word starts with `#` or normal word inside `<p>`.

```
const Text = ({ content }) => (
    <div className="mt-2 mb-4 mx-4">
        <p className="text-sm text-justify">
            {content.split(" ").map((str) => {
                if (str.startsWith("#")) {
                    return <a href={`/${str}`} className="text-blue-500">{str} </a>;
                }
                return str + " ";
            })}</p>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Also you could have some context that provides urls keyed by that str like `const {urls} =useContext(urlContext)` and ```<a href={`/${urls[str]}`} ....```